# What are the multipliers next to badges?

Tags: support, badges

The badges page shows each one with a 'x NN'.  It's obvious that the number is
higher for harder badges but what exactly does this number mean?  Is it multiplying something specific or just decoration?

Comment: Actually, the lower the number, the harder the badge. Of course the Beta badge is now unattainable, so it's technically the hardest badge of all to get.

Comment: @AlanMunn: That and the bronze [Precognitive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/67/) badge.

Comment: Perhaps the hardest attainable badge is the gold [Unsung Hero](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/51/unsung-hero) badge. It requires a somewhat timid voting community - not so much here. As a minimum it requires 40 answers, 11 of which are accepted by the OP with a score of zero.

Comment: You guys are right, the number is lower the harder. At least I was right that they're correlated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The number indicates the number of that specific badge that has been awarded to users on the site. Take the following snapshot as an example:

[image]

- [Benefactor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/47/benefactor): 138 people have awarded a bounty on their own question manually (this badge can only be awarded once). Clicking on the badge shows:

  [image]
- [Civic duty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/32/civic-duty): 174 people have voted more than 300 times. Clicking on the badge shows:

  [image]

And so you can cycle through these and see who/which post has these been awarded to/for. Some are awarded once, while others can be awarded multiple times.